# Override the activity toolbar inside a fragment (and restore when the fragment is destroyed)

Tags: java, android, fragment

I'm trying to hide the activity toolbar inside a fragment when it is attached to the screen. And restore the toolbar when the fragment is detached.

How can I achieve this in a smooth way?

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment you can do it by

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
    //Replace AppCompateActivity with the activity class you used.
}

@Override
public void onDetach(){
    super.onDetach();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
    //Replace AppCompateActivity with the activity class you used.
}
```